# Basic Hello World app isn't building with ndk-build (.mk files)

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I'm using *Android Studio* 2.2.3 with *OpenCV* SDK. I started with the default *Hello world* application (*C++* option selected). The project was configured (by default) to use *CMake*.

*OpenCV* SDK uses the `.mk`-based build system. I modified the `build.gradle` for my application as follows (commented 3 lines, added 3 lines for `ndk-build`):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.ac.iitb.sc.arms.sample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
//        cmake {
//            path "CMakeLists.txt"
//        }
        ndkBuild{
            path 'src/main/cpp/Android.mk'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

My current directory tree looks like:

```
APP
├── app.iml
├── build.gradle
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── libs
├── proguard-rules.pro
└── src
    ├── androidTest
    │   └── java
    │       └── test 
    │           └── ...
    ├── main
    │   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
    │   ├── cpp
    │   │   ├── Android.mk
    │   │   ├── Application.mk
    │   │   └── native-lib.cpp
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── test
    │   │       └── sc
    │   │           └── arms
    │   │               └── sample
    │   │                   └── MainActivity.java
```

where `Android.mk` looks like

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= /home/homer/Desktop/OpenCV-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

include $(OPENCVROOT)/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl
LOCAL_MODULE:=MyLibs

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Also I have placed the `Application.mk` file with the following content in the `cpp` directory

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

And also *Android* is not able to resolve the `stringFromJNI()` function as shown

[image: android unable to resolve the function]

When I build the application it shows no error. When I run the app it immediately crashes with the `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`: `couldn't find "libnative-lib.so"` error.

The `libnative-lib.so` is supposed to be generated by `ndk-build`, it is not being built. I suspect that it is a *Gradle* configuration related issue.

### EDIT:

Here is the content of `native-lib.cpp`:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"
jstring
Java_e2016_iitb_1projects_vvy_sample_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 potential problems I can see here:

- in your `build.gradle` the `defaultConfig` block still uses the `cmake` build tool within the `externalNativeBuild` block. It should be `ndkBuild` too.
- regarding the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, you might have encountered a [common mistake](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_ULE). One of the solutions for preventing this kind of exception is to make sure the *C* method signature is fully correlated to your app (*Java*) package name.